# Entering the Schengen area with one passport and legally remaining with another

Tags: schengen, europe

I have obtained my visa to study in the Schengen area. It is valid from September 4. However my flight is on September 2 (flights are full and I cannot change it). I can enter the Schengen area as a tourist on my second passport and then once my visa is valid I can remain and study in that area legally with my other passport.

Will it be an issue if I do not have an exit stamp on the passport I have entered? Will it be an issue if I do not have an entering stamp on the passport that carries my student visa? How can I approach this issue without having to fly out of the Schengen area with the passport I have entered and reenter with my valid visa?

I plan to study in Spain.

Comment: Why would you need to use your second passport?  Is it from a different country?  If the visa is in the passport of a country that doesn't require tourist visas, you ought to be able to use that passport to enter before the student visa becomes valid.

Comment: @phoog In that case, would they need to change their immigration status? (Is there such a thing in Schengen?)

Comment: @phoog I need to use the second passport because I can only enter schengen area with the passport  that has a student visa with a visa (it is a require even for tourists)

Comment: @DavidRicherby, that exactly what I would like to know. Otherwise my last restort would be travelling to the UK for a day and reentering the schengen area when my visa is valid. but I want to avoid that.

Comment: @MariaMaria there's nothing in the Schengen codes that requires you to leave and re-enter.  But national law might require it.  We can't answer the question with any degree of certainty without knowing what country you plan to study in.  Also, since it concerns a long-term visa, this question probably belongs on [Expatriates.SE] rather than here.

Comment: As you'll be in Spain, you could avoid flying by traveling over land to Gibraltar or by ferry to Morocco, but unless you're in the south that is unlikely to be better than flying.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it:

- You have a Spanish D (long-stay) visa valid from September 4th.
- You have two citizenships. One would require a visa, and the passport has the Spanish visa in it. The other does not require a visa.

I think your concern about missing stamps is misplaced. You are traveling with a combination of passports and disjointed stamps are common for dual citizens.

We have [several](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79143/how-to-switch-from-resident-visa-to-tourist-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area) [answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69331/need-i-leave-and-reenter-the-schengen-area-after-my-work-visa-expires-to-become?noredirect=1&lq=1) on going from long-stay to tourism, the opposite direction but fundamentally the same you are doing here.